# Link a directory(with its own files and folders) to another directory

Tags: command-line, symbolic-link

I am trying to understand how to use the `ln` command but every link keeps turning out to be red. When I try to open the folder I get this error:

```
Too many levels of symbolic links
```

I am inside a folder called `/test`. Inside `/test`, I have another directory called `hello` and `hello` has a file called `index.html`. I want make a link to this folder (and everything inside) to the `/var/www/` folder. I do this:

```
cd /test
ln -s hello/ /var/www/
```

This makes the `hello` folder inside `/var/www` red and I get the error above when I try to open it. How can I do this properly? `ln` still doesn't make much sense to me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out I needed to give the full path. Instead of `ln -s hello/ /var/www/`, you should write the full path of `hello`. In my case, it was the following:

```
ln -s /test/hello/ /var/www/
```

The folder inside `/var/www/` should be a blue color now with no errors when trying to open it.